# how to check in ajax form callback if form for failed validation

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I have a form and on and implemented a ajax submit callback which calls this function:

```
function popover_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    // watchdog("ajax_callback", "testing ajax callback", array(), WATCHDOG_ALERT);
    return '<div id="ajaxchanger">' . $form_state['values']['first']['field_firstname'] . '</div>';
}
```

How do I check if the form failed or passed validation within this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function popover_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $errors = form_get_errors();
  if( $errors ) {
    // error detected, do something
  } else {
    // everything is ok
  }
}
```

but your return value is not ok. You need to return an renderable array. You may want to try someting like this:

```
return array('#markup' => '<div id="ajaxchanger">' . $form_state['values']['first']['field_firstname'] . '</div>');
```

Comment: actually my return value works. Is this just not following the standards then?

Comment: yeah, something like that :) but if it works, I think it's ok. it isn't such a big deal...

Comment: A year later but I now understand I should have used a [renderable array](http://drupal.org/node/930760) as return value ;)