# How to trigger form AJAX callback if the form did not validate?

Tags: 7, forms

I attached an AJAX callback to first/last names on the registration form.
When user enters both, the callback generates automatically the username and shows it in the form.

The problem is that the callback is not executed if the form fails validation.
I want still to execute it, and if the user has entered first/last names, to show the username on the screen.

I found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/31177/10041) post here, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's simplified code I'm using:

```
function sample_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['first_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First name'),
    '#ajax' => array('callback' => 'sample_username_ajax_callback'),
  );
  $form['last_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last name'),
    '#ajax' => array('callback' => 'sample_username_ajax_callback'),
  );
  $form['#default_username_text'] = t('Username will be automatically generated.');
  $form['username'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="signup-username">',
    '#markup' => $form['#default_username_text'],
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
}

function sample_username_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  // Make sure that both first and last names are set.
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['first_name']) && !empty($form_state['values']['last_name'])) {
    $markup = t('Your username will be <b>@username</b>', array(
      // I have a processor function here, but for the sake of clarify I removed
      // it.
      '@username' => $form_state['values']['first_name'] . '.' . $form_state['values']['last_name'],
    ));
  }
  // Either the fields are empty, or the user deleted them.
  else {
    $markup = $form['#default_username_text'];
  }

  // Get the username element; we will update it and replace the old one with
  // this one.
  $element = $form['account']['username'];
  $element['#markup'] = $markup;

  // Build the commands.
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#signup-username', drupal_render($element));

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your callback and form building code? #callback AJAX function should be always executed. The problem may be how you configure the form.

Comment: Thanks for the message @tunic, I'll update the question now.

Comment: Are you sure callback is not ebing executed? May be your CSS selector (#signup-username) is wrong. Keep in mind that Drupal keeps track of generated ids. Usually after an AJAX callback regenerated elements with id have their id appended a numer (myid, then myid--1).

Comment: I checked the CSS selector after the form is submitted, and it's still the same. I'm also sure that the callback is not executed upon validation - I added a `watchdog()` line to log when it is called, but nothing.